# Cannot post result on the jsp from spring-mvc with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have problem coupling spring-mvc with ajax. I want to create a simple calculator provide to numbers in JSP post them and get sum as result. The values are send properly (according to the log - on the bottom of the post) but I cannot display the result on the jsp page.

My code:

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/springMVCTest/")
public class HelloController {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class.getName());

    @Resource(name = "addService")
    private MathClass mathClass;

    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "get");
        return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Integer add(@RequestParam(value = "inputNumber1", required = true) Integer x,
                      @RequestParam(value = "inputNumber2", required = true) Integer y, ModelMap model) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "x: " + x + " y: " + y + " sum: " + mathClass.add(x,y));
        return mathClass.add(x,y);
    }
}
```

MathClass.java
    @Service("addService")
    public class MathClass {

```
    public Integer add(Integer x, Integer y){
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
<body>

<h1>${message}</h1>

<div>
    Add Two Numbers:
    <br>
    <input id="inputNumber1" name="inputNumber1" type="text" size="5"> +
    <input id="inputNumber2" name="inputNumber2" type="text" size="5">
    <br>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Add">
    <br>
    <span id="sum">result</span>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#submitButton').click(function(){

            $.post("http://localhost:8080/springMVCTest/test",
                    {
                        inputNumber1: $("#inputNumber1").val(),
                        inputNumber2: $("#inputNumber2").val()
                    },
                    function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        $("#sum").text(data);
                    }
            );
//
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
        <!--http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache -->
        <!--http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">-->


    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and that is my data from the logger:

```
Mar 27, 2014 9:29:12 PM com.springapp.mvc.HelloController printWelcome
INFO: get
Mar 27, 2014 9:29:15 PM com.springapp.mvc.HelloController add
INFO: x: 2 y: 32 sum: 34
```

The calculation in java class are ok, however the sum is not send to the JSP. Do You have any clue why is that happening?

Edit:
According to the Chrome Inspector I got 406 Not Acceptable response.

Comment: Did you check what http response(if any) you get?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. However what I did, in the ajax $.post instead of function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        $("#sum").text(data);
                    } I put simply alert function and I got the message popped out, so according to the $.post api method finished with success

Comment: What's the response status? The logs might show correct results but that doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: You can use firebug to see the http communication between the browser and the server. http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-debugging-with-firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, I had not included in the pom.xml jackson-mapper-asl that is the reason why it did not work